# Find vertices of LineStrings within Polygon - Shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I would like to use Shapely to find the vertices that are located within the boundaries of a Shapely Polygon. So far, I could only manage to get it running by converting the LineString and the Polygon to a GeoPandas DataFrame and use the Geopandas `within(...)` function. Ideally, the function that I am looking for would return a list of Shapely Points that were either kept or are the ones that were within the Polygon.

Here a little code example of what I have done so far:

`fault_ls` and `interface_ls` are Shapely Linestrings.

```
# Creating a buffer around the fault trace
fault_polygon = fault_ls.buffer(radius)

# Creating GeoDataFrame from Polygon
fault_polygon_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [fault_polygon]}, crs=crs)

# Create lists with X and Y coordinates from LineString
x = [i[0] for i in interface_ls.coords]
y = [i[1] for i in interface_ls.coords]

# Creating GeoDataFrame from LineString
interface_ls_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x, y, crs=crs))

vertices_in = interface_ls_gdf[interface_ls_gdf.within(fault_polygon_gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'])]

vertices_out = interface_ls_gdf[~interface_ls_gdf.within(fault_polygon_gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'])]
```

`vertices_in` are the vertices within the buffer, `vertices_out` the ones outside that I want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Why not fully taking advantage of [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) in that case?

Let do the imports first:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint
import geopandas as gpd
```

Then read some dummy Shapefiles, one containing a single 'fault' line  and the other containing a network of let's say pipelines close to the fault:

```
fault_file = 'fault.shp'
pipeline_file = 'pipeline.shp'
# Load with fiona
fault_gdf = gpd.read_file(fault_file)
pipeline_gdf = gpd.read_file(pipeline_file)
```

Check what's in there:

```
>>> fault_gdf
   id       name                                           geometry
0   1  the_fault  LINESTRING (-50.34740 64.08437, -50.34060 64.0...

>>> fault_gdf.crs
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World.
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> pipeline_gdf
   id       name                                           geometry
0   1    primary  LINESTRING (-50.34277 64.09243, -50.33218 64.0...
1   2  secondary  LINESTRING (-50.27735 64.09024, -50.27442 64.0...
2   3  secondary  LINESTRING (-50.30269 64.08963, -50.30723 64.0...
3   4   tertiary  LINESTRING (-50.27442 64.08850, -50.27802 64.0...
4   5   tertiary  LINESTRING (-50.26885 64.08594, -50.26402 64.0...
5   6   tertiary  LINESTRING (-50.27064 64.08735, -50.27357 64.0...
```

Then build your buffer (warning, WGS84, buffer size in angle, not precise, you'd better work in a cartesian system):

```
fault_gdf['buffer'] = fault_gdf['geometry'].buffer(0.0032)
poly = fault_gdf.iloc[0]['buffer'] # Get the shape out for convenience
```

Then build a function to extract vertices of these linestrings:

```
def get_vertice_from_line(gdf):
    gdf['points'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: \
                                          MultiPoint([y for y in x.coords]))

    return gdf
```

And one function to get inside and outside vertices (which get written in two new columns as MultiPoints):

```
def get_points_in_and_out(gdf_lines, polygon):
    gdf_lines['in'] = gdf_lines['points'].intersection(poly)
    gdf_lines['out'] = gdf_lines['points'].difference(
        gdf_lines['points'].intersection(poly)
    )
    # Just in case; replace empty value by None to fix a bug when plotting
    gdf_lines['in'] = gdf_lines['in'].apply(lambda x: None if x.is_empty else x)
    gdf_lines['out'] = gdf_lines['out'].apply(lambda x: None if x.is_empty else x)
    gdf_lines.set_geometry('points', inplace=True)

    return gdf_lines
```

Call these two guys in a row:

```
pipeline_gdf = get_vertice_from_line(pipeline_gdf)
pipeline_gdf = get_points_in_and_out(pipeline_gdf, poly)
```

Check:

```
>>> pipeline_gdf
   id  ...                                                out
0   1  ...  MULTIPOINT (-50.34277 64.09243, -50.33218 64.0...
1   2  ...  MULTIPOINT (-50.27735 64.09024, -50.27442 64.0...
2   3  ...  MULTIPOINT (-50.34126 64.08875, -50.33757 64.0...
3   4  ...                         POINT (-50.27442 64.08850)
4   5  ...  MULTIPOINT (-50.25750 64.08607, -50.25240 64.0...
5   6  ...                         POINT (-50.27064 64.08735)

[6 rows x 6 columns]
```

Hmm, maybe better with an image:

[image: Check]

Plot for convenience:

```
def plot_gdf(fault_gdf, pipeline_gdf):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,16))
    fault_gdf.plot(color='maroon',ax=ax)
    fault_gdf['buffer'].plot(color='sandybrown', alpha=0.4, ax=ax, zorder=-9)
    pipeline_gdf['in'].plot(color='limegreen', markersize=500, ax=ax)
    pipeline_gdf['out'].plot(color='lightcoral', markersize=500, ax=ax)
    pipeline_gdf.plot(color='blue', marker='+', markersize=200, ax=ax)
    plt.grid()

plot_gdf(fault_gdf, pipeline_gdf)
```

And there we go:

[image: Results]

Compared with the original shapes in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/):

[image: QGIS shapes]

You can then export your two sets of points to a database for example, keeping whatever original attributes they have. Don't worry, shapely is still used under the hood, but you add the advantages of dealing with dataframes.